# Black screen when trying to draw model [read edit]

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm trying to make a world object that can use a camera and draw multiple models at once, each with their own position (and rotation, etc. in the future). Except it comes up with a black screen and I don't know why.

I've tried changing the way the matrices are created, adjusted the positions, and nothing.

World:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

using Simple3DWorld.Objects;

namespace Simple3DWorld
{
    public class World
    {
        public Camera Camera;
        public ModelObject[] Objects;

        public World()
        {
            Camera = new Camera(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Vector3.Zero);
            Objects = new ModelObject[100];
            AddObject(new Landscape(new Vector3(0, 0, -1)));
        }

        public void AddObject(ModelObject obj)
        {
            bool added = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < Objects.Length && !added; i++)
            {
                if (Objects[i] == null)
                {
                    Objects[i] = obj;
                    added = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gt)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Objects.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Objects[i] != null)
                {
                    Objects[i].Update(gt);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Draw()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Objects.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Objects[i] != null)
                {
                    Objects[i].Draw(Camera);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Camera:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Simple3DWorld
{
    public class Camera
    {
        public Vector3 Position;
        public Vector3 LookingAt;
        public float FieldOfView;
        public float AspectRatio;

        public Camera(Vector3 pos, Vector3 lookAt)
        {
            Position = pos;
            LookingAt = lookAt;
            FieldOfView = MathHelper.PiOver4;
            AspectRatio = STDW.Width / STDW.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

ModelObject:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Simple3DWorld
{
    public class ModelObject
    {
        public Model Model;
        public Vector3 Position;

        public ModelObject(Model model, Vector3 pos)
        {
            Model = model;
            Position = pos;
        }

        public virtual void Update(GameTime gt)
        {

        }

        public virtual void Draw(Camera camera)
        {
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                    effect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
                    effect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
                    effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(camera.Position, camera.LookingAt, Vector3.UnitZ);
                    effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(camera.FieldOfView, camera.AspectRatio, 1f, 100f);
                }

                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, I have made sure that all methods are being called correctly. What should be showing on screen is my landscape model.

EDIT: Solved. For some stupid, frustrating reason, MonoGame will not render your models if your camera's X and Y (not the up vector) are both 0. If anyone could somehow explain this, I would be infinitely grateful.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Monogame, but wasn't SpriteBatch required to draw?

Comment: That's for 2D textures, not 3D models.

Comment: I see, looks like you solved it on your own already. You can post your edit as an answer, so it's also clear for everyone else that this is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Camera's `Position` and `LookAt` vectors cannot both be equal on the two axes perpendicular to the `Up` vector. This results in a NaN(not a number).

This situation can also be characterized as a [Gimbol Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock), since the rotations about the `X(Roll)` and `Y(Pitch)` axes are aligned, making it impossible to determine the `Z(Yaw)` from the information provided.

The problem occurs in the creation of the `View` matrix in the following line:

```
effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(camera.Position, camera.LookingAt, Vector3.UnitZ);
```

Substituting the argument values:

```
effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0,0,1), new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(0,0,1));
```

Annotated partial source for [CreateLookAt](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/6f34eb393aa0ac005888d74c5c4c6ab5615fdc8c/MonoGame.Framework/Matrix.cs#L761) at implementation(see [here](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/6f34eb393aa0ac005888d74c5c4c6ab5615fdc8c/MonoGame.Framework/Matrix.cs#L747) for pass the through call)

```
 public static void CreateLookAt(ref Vector3 cameraPosition, ref Vector3 cameraTarget, ref Vector3 cameraUpVector, out Matrix result)
 {
    var vector = Vector3.Normalize(cameraPosition - cameraTarget);
```

`Normalize((0,0,1) - (0,0,0))` -> `(x,y,z)/Length`

`Length = (0 - 0)² + (0 - 0)² + (0 - 1)²` -> 1

`(0/Length,0/Length,1/Length)` -> `(0/1,0/1,1/1)` ->`(0,0,1)` *OK

```
    var vector2 = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(cameraUpVector, vector));
```

Working inside out:

`Cross((0,0,1),(0,0,1))` -> `(y1 * z2 - z1 * y2, z1 * x2 - x1 *z2, x1 * y2 - y1 *x2)` ->

`(0 * 1 - 1 * 0, 1 * 0 - 0 * 1, 0 * 0 - 0 * 0)` -> `(0,0,0)` *Mathematically OK, Geometrically undefined(does not define a plane perpendicular to the input points)

`Normalize(Cross((0,0,1),(0,0,1)))` -> `Normalize(0,0,0)`

`Length = (0 - 0)² + (0 - 0)² + (0 - 0)² -> 0`

`(0/Length,0/Length,0/Length)` -> `(0/0,0/0,0/0)` ->`(NaN,NaN,NaN)` *UH-OH

The `NaN` results from the division by zero with the 0 being unsigned as defined by [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero).

Since any operation on a `NaN` results in `NaN`. The `NaN` propagates to the `World` and `Projection` matrices, resulting in a black screen.

To put it another way:

If you were standing up looking (`Camera.Position`=`(0,0,6)`), ignoring the fact your head has to tilt to see them, at your feet(`Camera.LookAt` =`(0,0,0)`), is it possible to determine the compass direction, where the `Up` vector equals `Vector3.UnitZ`, that you are facing? No. It is not possible, you could be facing any direction on the plane.

If I ask for the World coordinate one unit in front of your feet`(1,0,0)`, I can tell which direction you are facing.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up way better than me. Please understand that I am very new to 3D programming, so I couldn't of provided an answer as detailed as this one. I marked this as the answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. All I had to do was move my camera off of 0,0,0. 0,1,0 1,0,0 and 1,1,0 all seemed to work, which means the camera's other two coordinates (not the one that determines whether it's up or down) can't be at the origin. Not too sure why this is a thing, but at least it's fixed now.

Comment: This is not correct. There is nothing to prevent the Camera from being placed in the World at any valid coordinate(including the origin or (0,0,a)).  The only restriction is the Camera's  `LookAt` and `Position` vectors cannot be at the same `X` and `Y` coordinates given an `Up` vector of  `(0,0,1)`